# add icon button in table flutter

Tags: flutter, button, tablerow

```
 body: Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(25),
      child: Table(
        border: TableBorder.all(),
        columnWidths: {
          0: FractionColumnWidth(0.14),
          1: FractionColumnWidth(0.6),
          2: FractionColumnWidth(0.3),
        },
        children: [
         // here to add iconButton
          buildRow(['No.','List of Books','Action'], isHeader: true),
          buildRow(['1','Harry Potter Philosopher','Action']),
          buildRow(['2','Sleeping Beauty','Action']),
          buildRow(['3','Beauty and The Beast','Action']),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );

   // here List<String>
  TableRow buildRow(List<String> cells, {bool isHeader = false}) => TableRow(
    children: cells.map((cell) {
      final style = TextStyle(
        fontWeight: isHeader? FontWeight.bold : FontWeight.normal,
        fontSize: 18,
      );
      return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            (cell), //here error
            style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 15,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }).toList(),
  );
}
```

Here is i confused to declare icon button in the parameter buildRow cause it carry String but when i change to Widget it will appear the error at Text(cell). I want to add the iconButton in the third row of the table

Answer (score 1):

Just declare `List<Strings> cells` to `List<Widgets> cells` like below code:

**Use like this:**

```
 buildRow([Text('1'), IconButton(onPressed: (){}, icon: Icon(Icons.edit))], isHeader: true),
```

Comment: return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            (cell),
            style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 15,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );

Comment: i have error at Text((cell))

Comment: Can you please share your full code for better understanding?

Comment: i already update my full coding above